# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate using Dependency Injection in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependencies, blazor, code-injection

I have a service project that handles the retrieval and merging of PDFs and a repository project that has the context and Models.

Initially we created it with an API that was functional and decided it was too much overhead for a simple application and gutted the logic into a simple service and referenced it.

I'm attempting to call the methods within the service from the Blazor page , I have registered the Service in the startup file and injected the Services on the page for DI but I am now receiving the error below. Specifically it is in regards to the Context located in the repository that is being referenced by the Service.

I've played around with the injecting, the addition of the Services in the Startup file and various formatting changes to no avail.

Configure Services in the Startup file :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddTransient<IBOLService, BOLService>();
        services.AddTransient<IPDFService, PDFService>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddDbContext<CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IntegrationControl")));
       }
```

The main razor pages' inject and using excerpt :

```
@page "/download"
@using LAS.BOLDownloader.Models
@using System.IO;
@using System.Net.Http;
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using LAS.BOLDownloader.Data;
@using BOL.Data;
@using BOL.Services;


@inject IJSRuntime js

@inject Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime JS
@inject CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext IntegrationControlContext

@inject IHttpClientFactory clientFactory

@inject IBOLService _bolService 
@inject IPDFService _pdfService
```

The Service Class :

```
public class BOLService : IBOLService
    {
        private CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext _context;

        public BOLService(CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<byte[][]> GetDocuments(string searchString, string IdType, int SiteId)
        {

            var bolNumbers = searchString.Split(',');

            if (IdType == "BolNumber")
            {
                return await _context.Las2cpBolstaging.Where(o => bolNumbers.Contains(o.BolNumber.ToString()) && o.PlantId == SiteId).Select(o => o.BolDoc).ToArrayAsync();


            }
            else if (IdType == "ShipmentId")
            {
                return await _context.Las2cpBolstaging.Where(o => bolNumbers.Contains(o.BolNumber.ToString()) && o.PlantId == SiteId).Select(o => o.BolDoc).ToArrayAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

The context in the repository :

```
public partial class CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext : DbContext
    {
        public CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext()
        {
        }

        public CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext(DbContextOptions<CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Las2cpBoldocStaging> Las2cpBoldocStaging { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Las2cpBolstaging> Las2cpBolstaging { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LasBols> LasBols { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=dev-sql1;Database=Covia.Dev.IntegrationControl;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
            }
        }
```

The function using the injection :

```
 protected async Task GetBOL(int SiteId, string IdType)
    {
        var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();

        si.SiteId = SiteId;
        si.IdType = IdType;


        try
        {

            Process bp = new BOLProcess( _bolService, _pdfService);

            var bolPdf = bp.GetBOLs(si.searchString, si.IdType, si.SiteId).Result;

            bolResultsList = bp.GetResults(si.searchString, si.IdType, si.SiteId).Result;

            if (bolPdf != null && bolPdf.Length > 0)

            {

                await FileUtil.SaveAs(js, "BOLDocument.pdf", bolPdf);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
>   descriptor 'ServiceType: BOL.Services.IBOLService Lifetime: Transient
>   ImplementationType: BOL.Services.BOLService': Unable to resolve
>   service for type
>   'BOL.Repository.Models.CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'BOL.Services.BOLService'.
>
> Inner Exception InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service
>   for type 'BOL.Repository.Models.CoviaDevIntegrationControlContext'
>   while attempting to activate 'BOL.Services.BOLService'.

Comment: Are you using a Client-Side project ?

Comment: Its server side. @aguafrommars

Comment: Did you try to place AddDbContext at the bigining of ConfigureServices ?